# how do i send inputbox/textbox to a cell in excel and press enter?

Tags: javascript, excel

```
<script>

function gbid(s)    {
return document.getElementById(s);

}

function GetData(cell,row){
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("Someexcelfile.xlsx");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");

gbid('span1').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(3,3).Value;
gbid('span2').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(4,3).Value;
gbid('span3').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(5,3).Value;
gbid('span4').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(8,3).Value;

gbid('span6').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(10,3).Value;
gbid('span7').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(11,3).Value;
gbid('span8').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(12,3).Value;

gbid('span11').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(14,3).Value;
gbid('span12').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(15,3).Value;
gbid('span13').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(16,3).Value;
gbid('span14').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(17,3).Value;

}


function RetrieveMember(cell,row){
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("Someexcelfile.xlsx");
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");

var searchMember = document.getElementById('searchMember').value;

var Name = document.getElementById('searchMember').value;


gbid('span9').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(11,7).Value;
gbid('span10').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(12,7).Value;
gbid('span15').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(15,7).Value;
gbid('span16').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(16,7).Value;
gbid('span17').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(17,7).Value;
gbid('span18').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(7,3).Value;

excel_file.Close()
excel.Application.Quit()
}
</script>

<body onload="GetData()" />

<body bgcolor="#000000">
<table width="450">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#fafafa"><center>
    <span id="span1" width:'100%'; ></span><br />
    <span id="span2" width:'100%'; ></span><br />
    <span id="span3" width:'100%'; ></span></center>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#B6D7E6" >
<b>     <span id="span4" width:'100%'; ></span> : </b>
<input type="text" name="searchMember" id="searchMember" /> <a href="javascript:     RetrieveMember();">Search</a>
<br />
<br />
<span id="span6" width:"100%; ></span>&nbsp; <b><u><span id="span18" width:"100%; ></span></b></u>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#fafafa" > 
    <span id="span7" width:"100%; ></span> <br />
    <span id="span8" width:"100%; ></span> <br /> <br />
    <span id="span11" width:"100%; ></span> <br />
    </td>

    <td bgcolor="#B6D7E6" >
    <span id="span9" width:"100%; ></span> <br />
    <span id="span10" width:"100%; ></span> <br /><br /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#B6D7E6" > <span id="span12" width:"100%; ></span><br />
                <span id="span13" width:"100%; ></span><br />
                <span id="span14" width:"100%; ></span><br /><br />
    </td>
    <td bgcolor="#fafafa" >
                <span id="span15" width:"100%; ></span><br />
                <span id="span16" width:"100%; ></span><br />
                <span id="span17" width:"100%; ></span><br /><br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Okay, this code so far does almost everything I want it to do. It pulls existing info from the same excel file im going to use just fine. What I am trying to get it to do is send info from an inputbox/textbox to a specific cell in excel (and then have it automatically hit enter). That's it. I'm new to javascript and wondering if I can get a little help please. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: `excel_sheet.Cells(3,3).Value=yourInputValue;`

Answer (score 0):

To send a value fro the page to an Excel cell just reverse this expression:

```
gbid('span18').innerText = excel_sheet.Cells(7,3).Value;
```

to this:

```
excel_sheet.Cells(7,3).Value = gbid('span18').innerText;
```

I don't know what you intend by pressing Enter though. If I assume you are trying to respond to the Save file confirmation, then why not explicitly save the file:

```
excel_file.SaveAs("some location\somename.xlsx");
```

(assuming you *can* save using an ActiveXObject.)

BTW You shouldn't need `Application` in the following, as excel is already the application:

```
excel.Quit();
```

and JavaScript statements are semi-colon terminated. Even though it works without them, you should always use them.

Comment: Let me explain. Its is sending and pulling info from an excel interface. (I know its easier to just have it search data on its own, but its not an option for me) so what its doing is sending an Id, then pulling the results it generates. I tried the changes you suggested, but it doesn't seem to be pasting the info since it returns "not valid" which is info that is pulled when an error occurs in the excel interface. The excel.Quit(); doesn't close out the processes in the taskbar so I have to use application. I've gone in circles on this one and excel.application.quit(); works best.

Comment: You think its still possible for me to do this working with an interface?

Comment: I got it working. Only thing I have to figure out now is why it keeps creating a new process and not closing it out when its done. I just don't get why it wont close. I've used this before and worked fine. Ill have to look it up.

Comment: Glad you got it working. `Quit` won't release the resource, neither will `excel = null;`. It may be possible using an ActiveXObject; I'm not sure, but good luck!

Comment: by the way, the SaveAs line didn't work. this is the error code: Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Mon, 8 Jul 2013 21:31:22 UTC Message: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed Line: 46 Char: 2 Code: 0 URI: file:///Z:/SGL2.html

Comment: Did you supply a full path and filename, and do you have permissions to write to this location? I did mention that I am not sure if an ActiveXObject is able to save a file. Someone else might confirm or deny this.

Comment: I do have permission. I'm going to go with what you said and assume ActiveXObject will not allow me to save the file. We will have to live with it until I can find an alternative. Hey, thank you for all your efforts. You pointed me in the right direction! I wish I could mark you a 1 but my rep is still low. But thank you!